# Setting an @Published var to nil after no more events are received

Tags: swift, reactive-programming, combine

Consider the following code:

```
class MyController: NSObject, ObservableObject {

    //...

    @Published var myRapidlyChangingVar: MyEnum? = nil

    //...

    func calledAtHighFrequencyByExternalEvents(value: MyEnum) {
        myRapidlyChangingVar = value
    }
}
```

The value of `myRapidlyChangingVar` needs to be set to `nil` if no calls to `calledAtHighFrequencyByExternalEvents()` have been made for 1 second.

What is the simplest and cleanest approach to adopt to achieve this?

Strikes me as the sort of thing which Reactive programming should make incredibly simple, but unsure where to start or what to search for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily achive this with a [`debounce(for:scheduler:options:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/fail/debounce(for:scheduler:options:))

```swift
let cancellable = myRapidlyChangingVar
    .compactMap { $0 }
    .debounce(for: .seconds(1), scheduler: DispatchQueue.main)
    .sink { [weak self] _ in self?.myRapidlyChangingVar = nil }
}
```

Debounce has a fairly similar sibiling [`throttle(for:scheduler:latest:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/fail/throttle(for:scheduler:latest:))

You can read more about both in [this blogpost](https://rhonabwy.com/2019/12/15/combine-throttle-and-debounce/).

Comment: Many thanks for this Witek - it did indeed work. Another developer commented that the call to `compactMap()` should be moved before `debounce()` for performance reasons.

Comment: Happy it worked out for you. Good point with moving the compactMap, I will update my answer :)